# Error TF400443 when running TFS 2013

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

Fresh install of TFS 2013, and I receive this error message.

Any clues?

> TF400443: Failure loading extensions of type Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.IEnsureMachineExistsExtension, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
>   Plugin directory = C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Application Tier\Web Services\bin\Plugins.

Comment: I have been talking to the TFS team on this.

Comment: When do you get that error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feature is not avaible on your version, you must install last release, i had same problem

Comment: Can you specify "you must install last release"?